# how to find those VC++ codes who eat up my memory?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, memory, mfc

(i'm using VC++ 2010)
now i have lots of C++ code, when i run the app and do some operations, i found that it eat up 1.7G of memory. as the code is so large, it's impossible for me to check the code line by line.

i'm confused whether thare are some tools what can help me do that. i think the problem is not a isolated issue, somebody should experience it before.

this is one simple sample:

```
while(1)
{
  int* p = new int;
}
```

then, the codes can eat up my memory. my goal is to find the code like this. maybe the problematical  codes in my program are not so clear.

anyone can help me?

Comment: try searching for the `new` keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Microsoft debug diag, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798, it is the best memory leak detector I've used. Remember to set the symbols right.

Answer (score 1):

Use PurifyPlus from IBM. Here's the evaluation copy.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/r/rpp/